# Load balancing does not work correctly when scale pod

Tags: kubernetes

#### What happened:

When I performed a stress test on nginx, the nginx deployment scaled, but the newly created nginx pod did not have any load. If I stop the stress test for two minutes, all pods will start working normally. As shown in the picture below:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWVsg.png)

#### What you expected to happen:

Once the pod is created and running through hpa, it can participate in load balancing normally.

#### How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):

Create bitnami/nginx use helm:

```
# helm get values nginx -ntest-p1
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  maxReplicas: 40
  minReplicas: 1
  targetCPU: 30
  targetMemory: 30
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 128Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 128Mi
```

#### Anything else we need to know?:

My test tool: http_load
If I start a stress test during scaledown, it told me no route to host err

#### Environment:

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): v1.18.8-aliyun.1

Cloud provider or hardware configuration: aliyun

```
OS (e.g: cat /etc/os-release): Alibaba Cloud Linux (Aliyun Linux) 2.1903 LTS (Hunting Beagle)

Kernel (e.g. uname -a): Linux 4.19.91-23.al7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 23 18:02:34 CST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Network plugin and version (if this is a network-related bug): flannel:v0.11.0.2-g6e46593e-aliyun
```

Others:

kube-proxy mode is ipvs, and other config is default.

same issue on github: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/101887

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with http_load and the documentation is quite sparse.
From your observation I assume that http_load uses HTTP keepalive, therefore reusing TCP connections. Kubernetes does loadbalancing on the TCP level, so only new connections will reach the added replicas.

You can either configure nginx to not provide keepalive, which will reduce the efficiency for regular use cases or start multiple http_load instances once the scale up has occurred to observe the effects.

Comment: thank for your answer. I have tried the methods you said, but got the same result. And I find the same issue as mine here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81775

Comment: That is indeed a different issue caused by ipvs, not the keep alive as suspected.